# How to generate Inputs for models using Html Helpers in MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Is it possible to generate inputs for strongly typed view using HTML helpers? If so how do u reference the model? For example if I need to use a input for a name in my view I can use the following statement.

`@Html.EditorFor(model => model.user.Name)`

After checking the page source of the mvc view output generated without helper I think that if I output the following string from my helper it should work to bind the input to the model.

```
<input class="text-box single-line" id="model_user_name" name="model.user.name" type="text" value="">
```

Is this possible? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both of those approaches will work. MVC will just examine the `name` property of items submitted in the form data, and bind them to your model in the Controller method.

The second method you've displayed is sometimes the only way to do it, for example when you want to bind a collection of complex objects to your model.

If you're trying to display something from your model, remember you can do `@this.Model.property` too.